# using Multer to add array

Tags: express, multer

I am using multer to add an array of images to my product document, I am getting the right name into the uploads folder, but undefind as a name in postman.

This is the code I tried:

```js
router.put(
  "/gallery-images/:id",
  uploadOptions.array("images", 10),
  async (req, res) => {
    if (!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
      res.status(400).send("Invalid product ID");
    } //product ID validation
    const files = req.files;
    let imagesPaths = [];
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/public/upload/`;
    if (files) {
      files.map((file) => {
        imagesPaths.push(`${basePath}${file.fileName}`);
        console.log("uhu", file);
      });
    }
    let product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        images: imagesPaths,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    if (!product) return res.status(500).send("The product cannot be updated");
    res.send(product);
  }
);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with this change:

```
const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/public/upload/`;

if (files) {
  // files.map((file) => {
  //   imagesPaths.push(`${basePath}${file.fileName}`);
  // });

  imagesPaths = files.map((file) => {
    const fileName = file.filename;
    return `${basePath}${fileName}`;
  });
}
```